basic assembly function giving memory error
I'm a beginner to assembly and taking an online crash course for it. One of the last challenges of the course is about function writing and calling. The idea is im supposed to recreate this function:

  str_lower(src_addr):
    i = 0
    if src_addr != 0:
      while [src_addr] != 0x00:
        if [src_addr] <= 0x5a:
          [src_addr] = foo([src_addr])
          i += 1
        src_addr += 1
    return i


where src_addr is contained in rdi and i is rax. rdi is going to be randomly given a value and [rdi] contains a byte of information. The function foo is contained at 0x403000. The following is my assembly code to recreate the function:

.intel_syntax noprefix
jmp _start
str_lower:
    xor rax, rax
    pop rbx
    mov rdi, [rsp]
    cmp rdi, 0
    jnz if
    jmp return
    if:
        cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0x0
        jnz while
        jmp return
        while:
            cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0x5a
            ja increment
            innerif:
                mov rcx, [rdi]
                push rcx
                call 0x403000
                pop rcx
                mov [rdi], cl
                inc rax
            increment:
                cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0
                inc rdi
                jnz while
    return:
        push rax
        push rbx
        ret
_start:
push rdi
call str_lower
pop rax


Sorry if the code has a little spaghetti but hopefully its readable. My issue here is the code compiles but when I pass it in the file supposed to check my challenge, pass in the rdi values, and give me my flag it gives me the error "Your program has crashed!   Invalid memory fetch (UC_ERR_FETCH_UNMAPPED)". The program is looping until rax and rdi are very large which is why it crashes I just have no reason why it loops forever. I have looked over and changed this code for about 4 hours I am so lost this was my last resort lol.
Im a beginner to functions so my program has had many kinks worked out but so far I've tried changing the pointer header for [rdi] in the cmp lines to "byte ptr"instead of "dword ptr" honestly Im at a complete loss for why it's acting like this but Im sure its an easy fix.

As per standard calling convention, both rax and rdi are caller saved. If you need their values preserved across a function call, you have to do so yourself. Your stack usage is very confusing. You are not supposed to remove the return address from the stack, and the result should just be left in rax and not pushed onto the stack. Unless your course specifies that for whatever strange reason. That applies to the foo function as well. Also the cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0 at increment: is useless and the jnz while should be jmp (jnz happens to work but is confusing).

And that last jnz while should be jmp if.

At the end of the while loop you have the following sequence:
cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0
inc rdi
jnz while

The inc of rdi affects the ZF flag, so you will always jump back to the beginning of the loop until the program crashes. Change it to:
inc rdi
cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0
jnz while

to ensure you are testing for the end of the string.
You also have a couple of sequences like:
cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0x0
jnz while
jmp return

where the label jumped to is the next instruction. Your code would probably read better by changing it to:
cmp byte ptr [rdi], 0x0
jz return


Damn so does changing the value of a register alter the result of the cmp command even if the cmp command happened before the change of the register? Thats pretty funny if thats true since I thought I was smart to put inc rdi after the cmp command as I thought it wouldn't change the zero flag. Thanks for the answer I really appreciate it.

@tjwells: Nearly all x86 arithmetic instructions alter the flags. This is explained in the instruction descriptions, which you should always read.

Thanks, but as @NateEldredge states, you should always read the documentation. As I showed, you are comparing [rdi], 0 which sets or clears the zero flag. But you then execute an inc instruction which does the same, so you are jumping on the result of the inc instruction not the cmp.
